# Error: EMFILE, too many open files with Gulp.watch

Tags: gulp, gulp-watch, browser-sync

My gulpfile.js looks like this:

```
gulp.task('default', ['build', 'browser-sync'], function () {
    gulp.watch("**/*.css", ['bs-reload']);
    gulp.watch(["**/*.js", "!**/*/node_modules/**/*.*"], ['bs-reload']);
    gulp.watch("**/*.html", ['bs-reload']);
});
```

Even though I have excluded node_modules it is trying to add a watch to all node_modules.

How can exclude it?

Please note that the node_modules does not exist at root of the project, infect it is at above the root of the project, so why it is even bother including the same?

```
Error: EMFILE, too many open files '/Users/**/Documents/gits/tm/node_modules/browser-sync/lib/public/socket.io.js'
    at Object.fs.openSync (fs.js:438:18)
    at Object.fs.readFileSync (fs.js:289:15)
    at Object.utils.getSocketScript (/Users/**/Documents/gits/tm/node_modules/browser-sync/lib/snippet.js:109:19)
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try this as a more resilient drop in replacement for `fs`:

[graceful-fs](https://github.com/isaacs/node-graceful-fs)

Globally patch `fs` like this:

```
var realFs = require('fs')
var gracefulFs = require('graceful-fs')
gracefulFs.gracefulify(realFs)
```

Comment: where should this be patched ? I have many modules dependent on the `fs`